# Layout changes on chrome after refresh

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My website is working fine on Safari and Firefox, and kind of also on chrome.
When first entering the website on Safari and Firefox it looks correct. However on Chrome it looks different, until the website is refreshed. Then it sorts itself out when refreshed.
 [Here is the link to the website](http://www.party-rockers.dk/NyHjemmeside) (Remember to try in Chrome!)
* I have tried to limit the navigation bar from expanding with max-height, but then my links are simply starting to appear lower, and upon refresh they get to their normal position.
* I have also tried on a different computer with Chrome.
* I tried to clear browser history and also in private-mode in Chrome
* Locally **it works** as it should on Chrome.

Sorry for future users. I've tried to upload pictures, but my reputation is not high enough yet.

Comment: looks fine for me in google chrome

Comment: Are you using any sort of server caching or a 3rd party service like CloudFlare that might also need to be cleared? **Edit:** the navigation bar resizes for me too on refresh (v35.0.1916.153 on Linux)

Comment: @indivisible
Not that I'm aware of. It's hosted on one.com.
Forgot to mention it, but i already did try to disable margin-top: 50px

**EDIT**: here it is uploaded without     margin-top 50px [link](http://party-rockers.dk/NyHjemmeside2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#logo` block is pushing your `ul` down. That combined with the `margin-top` is giving all that extra space.

Pop your logo out of the normal flow to sort it (main.css::63):

```
#logo {
    ...
    float: left;
}
```

This appears to be working how you want it in FireFox, Opera and Chrome for me.
(I don't have safari or IE natively installed to test and I'm not going to start up some VMs just for them, I'll leave that for you if you wish to test on those browsers)